# Geant4 does not find Expat library

Tags: configuration, installation

I'm trying to install Geant4 10.00 on Linux Mint 15. I have the unzipped geant4 file geant4.10.00.p01 in the directory I made:

/home/mickmau5/Geant4

along with the required build file geant4.10.00-build. 
This site goes throught the installation process http://goo.gl/nzxpQG . I'm at the lengthy cmake command part and getting this error

```
mickmau5@linuxmint ~/Geant4/geant4.10.00-build $ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/mickmau5/Geant4/geant4.10.00.p01-install /home/mickmau5/Geant4/geant4.10.00.p01
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_LIBRARY EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindEXPAT.cmake:50 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/Modules/Geant4OptionalComponents.cmake:71 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Seems like I ought to download some things.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Geant4 [documentation](http://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/UserDocumentation/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/ch02s03.html):

> GEANT4_USE_SYSTEM_EXPAT (DEFAULT : ON)
>
> If set to ON, build Geant4 with an external install of Expat. In this
>   case, the Expat headers and library will be searched for under the
>   standard system paths. If these are not sufficient to locate the
>   required Expat installation, see the Advanced EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR and
>   EXPAT_LIBRARY options.
>
> Whilst Expat is installed on the vast majority of systems, it may be
>   missing in certain instances. In these cases, simply switch this
>   option to OFF and Geant4 will build and use its internal version of
>   Expat.
>
> REQUIRES : Expat library and headers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could fix it by downloading the expat-devel library.

To install expat-devel package (dnf package manager):

`dnf install expat-devel`