# Errors during installing Geant4 in CentOS7

Tags: cmake, geant4

I'm trying to install Geant4 (version is 4.10.07.p01) and I got error refering to expat library priorities. I find a similar problem here [Geant4 does not find Expat library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529103/geant4-does-not-find-expat-library) and I followed the advice given. Since it's the first time I get into non-Windows OS, it is hard for me to understand some things. I changed the value to OFF but now I get the errors:

1. CMake Error at analysis/g4tools/CMakeLists.txt:36 (install):
   install FILES given no DESTINATION
   #but there is no CMakeLists.txt file in analysis/g4tools
2. CMake Error at analysis/CMakeLists.txt:36 (include):
   include could not find load file:
   Geant4MacroLibraryTargets
   #but there is no CMakeLists.txt file in analysis
3. CMake Error at analysis/CMakeLists.txt:51 (GEANT_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET):
   Unknown CMake command "GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET"
   #but there is no CMakeLists.txt file in analysis

Any help is welcome

Comment: Why not just install expat?

Comment: "but there is no CMakeLists.txt file in analysis/g4tools" - The file [analysis/g4tools/CMakeLists.txt](https://gitlab.cern.ch/geant4/geant4/-/blob/master/source/analysis/g4tools/CMakeLists.txt) clearly exists... but under `source/` directory. It smells like you configure the project with `source/` being as **source directory**. This is wrong: you need to configure the project with **top-level** (https://gitlab.cern.ch/geant4/geant4/-/tree/master/) directory being as source.